# Missing methods in Python class inheritance?

Tags: python, oop

I am not very experienced with class inheritance. Please help me and have a look at the code below:

```
class Handle(STAFHandle):

    def __init__(self, HandleName):
        handle = STAFHandle.__init__(self, HandleName)
        self.initLogger(handle)

    def initLogger(self, handle):
        self.logger = Logging(handle, 'Test')

handle = Handle('test')
handle.logger.info('test')
```

it says submit method is not defined:

> ```
> result = handle.submit(system, service, logRequest) 
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'submit'
> ```

but if I change it to:

```
class Handle(STAFHandle):
    def __init__(self, HandleName):
        handle = STAFHandle.__init__(self, HandleName)

    def initLogger(self, handle):
        self.logger = Logging(handle, 'Test')

handle = Handle('test')
handle.initLogger(handle)
handle.logger.info('test')
```

it works. Why there is a difference? Thanks a lot!!

Cheers,
Zhe

Answer (score 4):

`STAFHandle.__init__` returns `None`. You probably want:

```
class Handle(STAFHandle):
    def __init__(self, handle_name):
        super(Handle, self).__init__(handle_name)
        self.initLogger()

    def initLogger(self):
        self.logger = Logging(self, 'Test')

handle = Handle('test')
```

Remember that `__init__` methods take as their first argument an object, and *modify* that object. So when you call `super(Handle, self).__init__(handleName)` you are changing the properties of `self` instead of returning a new object. The difference between your two examples is that the variable `handle` in the two calls to `initLogger` refers to different things.

Notice that I have replaced the explicit `STAFHandle.__init__` call with a `super` proxy; this is equivalent in this case but allows for more flexibility, since you can now change the inheritance of the class without breaking its `__init__`.

I've also changed `HandleName` to `handle_name` to conform with Python conventions (CamelCase refers to classes).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Actually I tried this way first but then got a different error:
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj

Comment: @Zhe: your base class is "old-style"; it doesn't derive from `object`. In the new type hierarchy *all* classes should so do. Once you change it everything should work.